# Android tablet presentations: networking and equipment?

Tags: tablet

To start, a bit about myself.  I follow instructions really well, but I'm otherwise clueless on the how or why that things work when it comes to electronics.  I've built PC's several times from parts, but only because I did what I was told, and everything worked out each time.

What I want to be able to do:  I want to be able to hand out two 10" Android tablets to my clients when I meet them at their homes to do real estate listing presentations.  I want both of those tablets to mirror a device that I hold, running a powerpoint presentation, so that as I move the presentation on and am talking, it will likewise shift on their screen (it can't be automated, because I get sidetracked by a lot of questions).  Essentially, I want them to be able to hold and look at my presentation, while being able to look up at me while I'm talking them through it.

Limitations:

1) I don't want to use the internet to accomplish this, as it wouldn't be professional for me to request to use their wifi, and some people don't have wifi.

2) I would also prefer not to use a mobile hotspot requiring a data plan if possible (though I'd consider it if there were no alternative).

3) I would really like to mirror on two devices from one, so that I can hand out more than one tablet to owners.  Again, if this isn't possible, one would do.

So is this possible?  Would this be something I could do with bluetooth, or perhaps a wireless router used to connect the devices offline?  I honestly have no idea, nor if I'm even on the right track.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 0):

There are many possibilities for making this happen using different apps/services. But...kindly note: Playing a same ppt from single source on all three devices (one yours, and two for your clients) doesn't seems to be possible until they are connected to the same WiFi router (may be a offline router) but to be able to share screens using some screen-cast app or remotely controlling their presentations using team viewer sought of apps, the basic necessity is, that they all must be on same subnet.

let me know if i can help you further in accomplishing your this task..

Hope that answer your query as of now..

---

Well dude, this part has nothing to do with your question asked above, Its just a little piece of advice from my side.

Instead of taking pain of carrying three 10" devices and those too wont be collectively able to cater the need of more then 2-5 of your clients, i would suggest you to carry [this device](http://www.samsung.com/uk/consumer/mobile-devices/smartphones/others/GT-I8530BAABTU). As this definitely seems to be more useful for the kind of solution you are looking for. :)